# Connecting to Oracle Database Using Python

Tags: python, oracle

I am trying to connect to Oracle database using the following script;

```
import cx_Oracle
username = user
password = pwd
host = host
port = '1521'
service = service
dbconn = cx_Oracle.connect(username + '/' + password + '@'+ host + ':' + port + '/' + service)
```

But I got the following error;
`TNS:Connect timeout occurred`

Can anybody please suggest me what is going wrong here?

Comment: python version?? and oracle version?

Comment: @Exprator Python Version: 3.5.1, Oracle: 10g

Comment: it wont work bro, cx_python works with upper 11i or upper version

Comment: @Exprator any alternative suggestion?
How about using sqlanydb?
conn = sqlanydb.connect(uid = user, pwd = pwd, host = host + db). Still getting the same error.

Comment: you can try it but cx_python > 6 doesnt support less than 11i, you could use a older version of cx_python to check

Comment: @Exprator the cx_Oracle version is 5.2.1.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708998/cx-oracle-and-python-2-7 You can go through this and see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
# importing module 
import cx_Oracle 


# Create a table in Oracle database 
try: 

    con = cx_Oracle.connect('scott/tiger@localhost') 
    
    # Now execute the sqlquery 
    cursor = con.cursor() 
    
    # Creating a table srollno heading which is number 
    cursor.execute("create table student(srollno number, \ 
                    name varchar2(10), efees number(10, 2)") 
                    
    print("Table Created successful") 
    
except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as e: 
    print("There is a problem with Oracle", e) 

# by writing finally if any error occurs 
# then also we can close the all database operation 
finally: 
    if cursor: 
        cursor.close() 
    if con: 
        con.close()
```

Comment: A quick tip: if you use triple-quotes around the SQL string, you won't need the backslash.  This can make it easier to edit & work with SQL in Python.  (PS your answer is off topic, since it doesn't address the connection error, which is likely a connection string issue, or a network issue!)